# Can I sculpt images as planes?

Tags: image, sculpting, video

I'm new to Blender, and I'm trying to figure out how can I distort images or videos 3-dimensionally. I'm importing an image or video as 'images as planes', going to sculpting mode and trying to sculpt the surface on the plane, but it doesn't do anything. When I enable dyntopo, then it works, but the image is gone. It also works in 'edit mode', but then it's too slow and it's too geometrical. I would like to achieve more organic and less precise shapes, like in [Google Street View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Street_View).

Is it possible to sculpt 'images as planes'?

---

Great! Thank you for all the tips! It works!
I'd have two more questions, since I do need some geometrical extrusions as well:

1. I want to place single vertices in order to copy/mark bigger, complex shapes that I see on the photo. So by holding Ctrl + right click, I can add a single vertex and I can finish the loop by merging the last and the first vertex points. But it still floats in the space and it's not 'snapped' onto the image /plane. How do I create freehand vertices (loopcuts?) on a face/ the plane? Or how do I link those vertices with the picture plane?
2. Then I'd like to extrude that shape, but only one side of it. E.g: if there is a door on the photo, I can extrude it. But how do I 'open the door'? I mean, the left side stays on the surface and the right side extrudes/comes forward in perspective?

I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with this! When I'm watching/reading tutorials I can't find the right answers...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_ikG-u_6r0 check this video if you want to try the modelling way instead of sculpting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just have to subdivide the plane before.

So select the plane, and right mouse click → subdivide.

Then choose here (number of cuts) a big enough number for your sculpting. This depends on your size of your plane. e.g., 20.

[image]

You will see this dialog directly after you tapped on "subdivide" in the bottom left corner if you tap on this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "yes"
The sculpting needs a lot of geometry so, when you import the plane there are just four vertices.
[image]

You can add the geometry by subdividing it or using subdivision surface modifier (you can also use multi res modifier if it's a complex sculpt) and you are able to sculpt.
[image]

The reason why it doesn't work with dynamic topology is that, dynamic topology distorts your uv's (where the image texture is stored) by adding geometry in a non-preservative way.

[image: uv map]

[image]

But I wouldn't suggest you to sculpt the images as planes although it works since, the image might get distorted while stretching.

[image]

I prefer modelling using loopcuts while working with images as planes.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is quite simple. Just subdivide the plane go into sculpt mode and it would work it may look low poly if you didn't subdivide it enough.